# need changes to watir/loader.rb to make webdriver-user-agent work

Tags: user-agent, watir-webdriver

I am using webdriver-user-agent mentioned here – http://watirwebdriver.com/mobile-devices/
This is the code I am using when trying out this gem
Browser: FF/Chrome
Ruby: 1.9.3 / Selenium :2.30.0 / Watir : 4.0.2

```
http_client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
http_client.timeout = HTTP_TIMEOUT
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
device = ENV["DEVICE"]
orientation = ENV["ORIENTATION"]
driver = UserAgent.driver(:browser => :firefox, :agent =>device, :orientation=>orientation)
devices = UserAgent.resolution_for(device,orientation)
UserAgent.resize_inner_window(driver,devices[0],devices[1])
Watir::Browser.new driver
```

Now when the last statement is executed, i get the following error

```
(STEP) Launching FIREFOX (using web driver user agent)……
browser:
#

undefined method `to_sym’ for # (NoMethodError)
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/watir-4.0.2/lib/watir/loader.rb:42:in `load_driver_for’
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/watir-4.0.2/lib/watir/loader.rb:8:in `new’
```

Based on some investigation, problem is happening at highlighted line below as its trying to .to_sym on the selenium webdriver object.

```
def load_driver_for(browser)

if browser && browser.to_sym != :ie && Watir.driver == :classic
Watir.driver = :webdriver
end
Watir.load_driver
end
```

But if we add a line like given below, this gem is working as expected.

```
def load_driver_for(browser)

if “#{ENV["BROWSER"]}”.eql?(“chrome_useragent”)||”#{ENV["BROWSER"]}”.eql?(“firefox_useragent”)
Watir.driver = :webdriver
else
if browser && browser.to_sym != :ie && Watir.driver == :classic
Watir.driver = :webdriver
end
Watir.load_driver
end
end
```

since this is watir code outside of our framework, this is not the right way to do this, any suggestion on how to avoid this situation ?

Comment: Is this not the same as the bug you already logged - [Issue 6](https://github.com/alisterscott/webdriver-user-agent/issues/6)?

Comment: yes it is, but after i read your blog[link](http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/browserattach-method-undefined-in-watir-4-0/), i suspected that there is a solution to my problem based on how we require watir/watir-webdriver, so posted here  to see if i am missing anything, your answer helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is reproducible when you do:

```
require 'watir'
require 'webdriver-user-agent'
driver = Webdriver::UserAgent.driver(:browser => :chrome, :agent => :iphone, :orientation => :landscape)
browser = Watir::Browser.new driver
browser.goto 'tiffany.com'
browser.url.should == 'http://m.tiffany.com/International.aspx'
```

You can fix the issue by requiring watir-webdriver directly instead of through the watir metagem. Change the first line to:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
```